# Why and how does Symfony fill undefined view variable with null values in prod environment?

Tags: php, symfony

Consider the following PHP template:

```
<?= var_dump($myVariable) ?>
```

This is rendered with the following controller code:

```
public function myAction() {
    return $this->render("MyBundle::test.html.php");
}
```

Obiously, our variable `$myVariable` is not set in the template. When looking at this page in the `dev` environment we get an exception telling us that this variable is not defined. When looking at the page in the `prod` enviroment we get the output `null`.

I have debugged this for quite a bit but have not found the place where Symfony decides which variables need to be initialized with `null`. What happens behind the scenes is that Symfony calls `export` on the array of view variables (which is empty in our case) and then calls `require` on the view template itself. Funnily enough, when debugging the view, the variable is never defined, neither in `dev` nor in `prod`. But still there is different output for these two environments.

So my questions are:

- How does Symfony do this?
- Is this intended behavior?
- Is this documented somewhere and I just missed it?
- Is there a way to change this behavior so that it will also fail in `prod` and write an error to the log file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've only just started with PHP and Symfony, but it seems to me it goes something like this:

1. Symfony will call the `require` on the template
2. Your template starts executing
3. PHP tries to evaluate `$myVariable`
4. PHP will trigger `E_NOTICE` level error as described in [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)

Here is where different environments come into play. Error level, which is defined under `debug.error_handler.throw_at` key in debug.xml is -1 (ALL) for dev and 0 (NONE) for prod. So for dev the `ErrorHandler` in Symfony will throw, for production it won't.